# How to sync folder in the web server with local git repo in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git

I am trying to configure Git in `Eclipse Kepler` and sync my local git repo with a folder in the local web server.

The project folder in my local git repo is located at `C:\Users\MYPC\git\mod_helloworld`.

My web server files are located at `D:\Install\xampp\htdocs\joomla\modules\mod_helloworld`.

Basically I will be working directly on the web sever files and would like to sync the `mod_helloworld` folder with the local git repo. I could not find an option to do this in Eclipse's Git Repositories.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to have `D:\Install\xampp\htdocs\joomla\modules\mod_helloworld` be an exact copy of `C:\Users\MYPC\git\mod_helloworld` then you could look into setting up a junction link.

The command to do so is:

```
mklink /j D:\Install\xampp\htdocs\joomla\modules\mod_helloworld C:\Users\MYPC\git\mod_helloworld
```

I would suggest trying this out with a temporary folder to see how it works with:

```
mklink /j D:\Install\linked_folder C:\Users\MYPC\git\mod_helloworld
```

By creating a junction this way all requests to D:\Install\linked_folder will actually be sent to C:\Users\MYPC\git but D:\Install\linked_folder will behave as a normal folder.

However, you should be careful as this means that any changes within C:\Users\MYPC\git\mod_helloworld would be reflected within the linked folder so if you checkout a development branch, the server folder would be serving up your development branch files until you checked out the stable release branch (assuming master) again.

As this is not ideal for you, you can make your `C:\Users\MYPC\git\mod_helloworld` folder into a bare repo from which you would add as a remote source for your `D:\Install\...\mod_helloworld` repository such as:

```
cd C:\Users\MYPC\git
mv ./mod_helloworld ./mod_helloworld_backup

mkdir mod_helloworld
cd mod_helloworld
git init --bare

cd D:\Install\xampp\htdocs\joomla\modules\mod_helloworld
git init
git add -A
git commit -m "commiting all server files to server repo"
git remote add folder file:///C:/Users/MYPC/git/mod_helloworld

git push folder master
```

You can work on your server files directly now as your 'local' repo while being able to then commit/push to 'remote' which is, in fact, C:\Users\MYPC\git\mod_helloworld

Comment: What would be the ideal development scenario in this case? Is there a better alternative to using the symlink?

Comment: You could, alternatively set up `C:\Users\MYPC\git\mod_helloworld` as a bare repo and make `D:\Install\xampp\htdocs\joomla\modules\mod_helloworld` a clone (and add the bare repo as a remote source). See edited answer for details.